# How openId Connect is Authentication protocol and OAuth2 not when both returns user info (Email address etc)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

E.g from facebook, OAuth2 returns user information like email, name etc so why it is said that OAuth2 is just a Authorization protocol and  openIdConnect is Identity Layer over OAuth2. Aren't we can use this email id (returned from OAuth2) to identify users and create them on our app datatabase ?
Also what extra information OpenIdConnect send to applications ? When to use OAuth2 and when to use openIdConnect ?

Answer (score 0):

What OpenID Connect brings to the table is the standardized identity token so that the client can in a standardized way get the detail about the user and then from that id-token create a local login session.

It also standardizes some other things that otherwise with OAuth 2.0 could be different depending on implementation. This makes interoperability and integration easier as more things are standardized.

This [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/why-use-openid-connect-instead-of-plain-oauth2) can give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

The lines are often blurred as you say, and usually what we want is practicality rather than security jargon, so hopefully this helps.

**OAUTH AND DELEGATION**

OAuth enables a user to consent to a third party accessing the user's resources, after which an access token is given to the third party.

**OAUTH AND SOFTWARE COMPANIES**

OAuth + OIDC is used in the vast majority of software scenarios, because it is web, mobile and API friendly. In corporate software there is usually no third party involved - so you don't have to use OAuth for delegation.

**OAUTH AND AUTHENTICATION**

There is nothing about authentication in OAuth standards. In practice though, there is always something there to make the user login and you then trust tokens issued.

**OPEN ID CONNECT**

This provides proof of authentication to the UI, in the form of a verifiable id token. The id token can enable extra security checks, as explained [here](https://medium.com/@darutk/understanding-id-token-5f83f50fa02e).

OIDC also provides some welcome standardisation in terms of endpoints and message / token formats, to make your application code simpler.

**WHAT TO DO?**

Always aim to use OIDC for your UI security - most providers require it these days. If some login / identity providers don't support it, you can make your UI do this, which is the preferred pattern anyway:

- Redirect to your Authorization Server using OIDC
- Federate to the Identity Provider using whatever they support